# Rust - Issue with macro rules

Tags: rust, macros

I'm trying to build the following macro that impls add-assign for various types by casting the type to an already impled type then carrying out the operation as expected:

```
macro_rules! assign_for_value {
    ( $type_to_assign:ty, $cast_to_type:ty, $Add_or_Sub_Assign:ty, $add_or_sub_assign:ty, $add_or_sub:tt ) => {
        impl $Add_or_Sub_Assign<$type_to_assign> for ValueTerm {
            fn $add_or_sub_assign(&mut self, rhs: $type_to_assign) {
                *self $add_or_sub= rhs as $cast_to_type;
            }
        }
    };
}

assign_for_value!(i8, i64, AddAssign, add_assign, +);
assign_for_value!(i8, i64, SubAssign, sub_assign, -);
```

I wanted to double it up as an assignment for all operation types although I'm getting the following error:

```
error: expected `::`, found keyword `for`:

impl $Add_or_Sub_Assign<$type_to_assign> for ValueTerm {
                                         ^^^ expected `::`
```

This error is bizarre and not really any help at explaining what I have done wrong. Can't seem to find anything similar to this on stackoverflow so thought I'd ask. Would be super grateful for any help on this:)

Comment: Rust macros don't concatenate text, they work on AST level. Once you've requested to parse `SubAssign` as a `ty`, you can't just stick a `<T>` to it to make it another kind of type. Similarly, `$add_or_sub=` will not work because `+=` is a single token, not the concatenation of the `+` token with a `=` token, but you have forced the `+` to be its own token.

Comment: ah ok I see, thanks @mcarton the info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `$Add_or_Sub_Assign` and `$add_or_sub_assign` into *identifiers* (`:ident`). That way they can be used as *part* of a type and method name respectively (the latter was never a type to begin with). You will need to follow what was mentioned in the comments and make `+=` a single token instead of trying to split it.

```
macro_rules! assign_for_value {
    ( $type_to_assign:ty, $cast_to_type:ty, $Add_or_Sub_Assign:ident, $add_or_sub_assign:ident, $add_or_sub:tt ) => {
        impl $Add_or_Sub_Assign<$type_to_assign> for ValueTerm {
            fn $add_or_sub_assign(&mut self, rhs: $type_to_assign) {
                *self $add_or_sub rhs as $cast_to_type;
            }
        }
    };
}

assign_for_value!(i8, i64, AddAssign, add_assign, +=);
assign_for_value!(i8, i64, SubAssign, sub_assign, -=);
```

See it running on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9608878ed272a6827b0d35766c288586).